# SED replacing content with single and double quotes

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed

I am trying to write a shell script to find a replace this line of code on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
//Code before script runs
/*define('FS_METHOD','direct');*/  

//Code after script runs
define('FS_METHOD','direct');

sudo sed -i "s@/*define('FS_METHOD','direct');*/@define('FS_METHOD,'direct');@g" /home/example/example.txt
```

After running this line of code I do not get any errors, but it does not remove the /* */ I believe this is because of the single quotes.  I have tried escaping them with a backslash but it doesn't work either.  Anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem is that `*` is an RE metacharcter so you need to escape it to have it treated literally:

```
$ sed "s@/\*define('FS_METHOD','direct');\*/@define('FS_METHOD,'direct');@g" file
define('FS_METHOD,'direct');
```

or more concisely:

```
$ sed "s@/\*\(define('FS_METHOD','direct');\)\*/@\1@" file
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

Comment: I tried both of these methods and neither have worked for me.  I ran both lines in my terminal on OSX and ubuntu and neither worked.  I cant think of what I would be doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you need to double-escape everything because you're running under sudo? idk... Does it behave as desired when you don't run it under sudo? Does it produce the expected output when you don't include the `-i` option (eliminating file permission issue).

Comment: Tried to use sudo and not use it and it gives the same result.  Although it does work if I remove the single quotes.

Comment: Not sure why it wasnt working but it is now working properly with this: 
`sed -i "s@/\*define('FS_METHOD','direct');\*/@define('FS_METHOD','direct');@g" file.txt`